# Form is not fetching value from radio button

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### Html form using bootstrap 3

```
<form action="valuecheck.php" onsubmit="return passcheck();" method="POST" id="signup-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email address</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email address" value="" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Enter Password" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Re-enter password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Re-enter Password" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Area of Education / Working</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="area" required>
            <optgroup label="Other Disciplines">
                <option value='Architect'>Architect</option>
                <option value='Journalism'>Journalism</option>
                <option value='Law'>Law</option>
                <option value='Management'>Management</option>
                <option value='Medical'>Medical</option>
                <option value='other'>other</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" required>Male</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" required>Female</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

### php file

```
<?php if(isset($_POST[ 'email'])&isset($_POST[ 'password1'])&isset($_POST[ 'password2'])&isset($_POST[ 'area'])&isset($_POST[ 'sex'])){ print_r($_POST); } ?>
```

### Results

```
Array ( [email] => uhiwarale@gmail.com [password1] => 1 [password2] => 1 [area] => Process Engineering [sex] => )
```

## Problem

Looks like form is not taking value from radio boxes. I removed the form group and radio-inline classes but still it is not fetching the value. Can anybody have solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

try changing this:

```
$_POST[ 'sex1']
```

to this:

```
$_POST[ 'sex']
```

You are sending `sex` in the posted string and you are accessing that with `sex1` which doesnot matches so the issue is here.

and also you have posted your php code which seems incorrect because of single `&` there should be `&&`:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST[ 'email'])&&
         isset($_POST[ 'password1'])&&
         isset($_POST[ 'password2'])&&
         isset($_POST[ 'area'])&&
         isset($_POST[ 'sex'])){ //<------change here to 'sex'
                   print_r($_POST); 
      } 
 ?>
```

Comment: Sorry for the error... I was trying to change all to sex1... but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get `sex1` when the radio button name is `sex`